# Downloading runtime issue in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I have Minecraft running on a Mac OS X Yosemite. When I click on it, a message shows me that it's "downloading runtime". I opened it a few times and it shows me the message again and again. Then I searched the web for answers that will help me get rid of it and then a sign popped-up in my browser saying that Minecraft can't open because Java isn't installed. But I heard that Java is not needed to open up Minecraft, right?

Although after an hour with my mom and I trying to sort out the problem I found out that Minecraft can be opened up by clicking the launcher.jar in `~/Library/Application Support/Minecraft`.

I was searching high and low for an answer for the problem I have specifically, so I decided to ask my question on how get rid of this "download runtime" thing when I run Minecraft directly.

Answer (score 1):

This download runtime is basically a file that the Minecraft launcher is trying to find. The file that Java is trying to find is called Java Runtime Environment. It couldn't find it on your computer, so it has to download it. What you can do to get rid of it is just download Java. It is the easiest approach to this whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download Minecraft from the site https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/ . You'll have to get rid of the old version, but everything will still be there! Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same problem on El Capitan. Disabling my anti virus let the download complete. I was using Avast.